# Add role when user react on message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to make script which give user role when user react to message. I have this code but it dont work.

Script:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'rolename');
if (message.channel.name !== 'channelname') {
  return;
} else {
  message.member.addRole(roleid);
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.addRole` is deprecated. Instead use:

```js
message.member.roles.cache.add(roleid)
```